# How do I configure tortoisehg to show copied files in the log (i.e. use the hg "-C" option)?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg

I want to easily tell which files where renamed when looking at the changelog using the tortoisehg UI.  The out-of-the-box config only shows that a file was added/removed (i.e. the standard hg log message without the -C option).

Comment: I recommend to search or open feature request in Issue Tracker of TortoiseHg project: http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issues/

Comment: Thanks.  [issue 388](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issue/388/renames-are-not-visualized-well-in) looks close enough.  I added a comment.

Comment: wtf? does markdown not work in comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do it with TortoiseHg now.